# Eclipse-PMD Configure ruleset globally

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pmd

So i am using the Plugin Eclipse-PMD (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/) in a shared version control enviroment.

We have multiple smaller projects in the entire project.

Out of the box it seems that this plugin requires individual configuration for every single project.
The way it works it that it searched for a .pmd file in the project and read information from that.

But it's really inconvenient to do that for 10-20 subprojects.

There is a general setting under Preferences -> PMD. But this doesn't seem to apply globally, even if that global checkbox is checked.

**What i basically want: I want to configure the plugin to respect a single ruleSet-file in one place.**

There is another problem with configuring it subproject-specific: I cannot configure a relative path for the ruleSetFile in the .pmd-file. 
The problem with absolute path is that the file is checked into version control ... so with every commit everyone else would have to readjust. 
I found this commit: https://github.com/pmd/pmd/pull/36 but i cannot seem to make it work the way it's roughly described.

So, did anyone achieve what i am looking for?

Edit: Actually i cannot even specify any other file that is not ".ruleset" in the .pmd-file as `<ruleSetFile>` **without specifying an absolute path**??

The default value for ruleSetFile is ".ruleset". So i thought, analogous to that, i could create a file in the **exact same dir**, call it fooRules.xml, and specify it via `<ruleSetFile>fooRules.xml</ruleSetFile>` but it can only find it if put the entire path to fooRules.xml in there?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [eclipse-pmd](http://acanda.github.io/eclipse-pmd/) (available in the Eclipse marketplace or via the update site `http://www.acanda.ch/eclipse-pmd/release/latest`). With eclipse-pmd you can configure your projects to use a single rule set file for several projects. It also stores its path relative to the workspace. You still have to configure each project individually though (for now, this will change in a future release).

To set up eclipse-pmd in the way you described you have to open the project properties of your first project, select the "PMD" property page and add the rule set. Select the rule set type "Workspace" and pick your rule set file.
For every other project you have to open the project's PMD property page where you'll find the previously selected rule set file which simply needs to be checked to activate.

If you set it up this way there will be a `.eclipse-pmd` file in each project containing the settings. If you check this into your version control system then no one else in your team has to set up anything (apart from installing eclipse-pmd).

Disclaimer: I wrote eclipse-pmd. Mostly because I had the exact same problems as you with the other plugin.

Comment: Isn't what i posted exactly the same plugin that you mentioned?
I will check what you posted out but from my understanding it is the same?

When you say relative to workspace ... The problem is that our devlopers did not copy the project into the workspace, you know? From my understanding this is mandatory to do, otherwise the "relative to workspace" won't help at all, because project files are not in the workspace? Is there any other way of reaching non-workspace files from an abstract level? If there really is no other way then i guess i have to force others to copy all files into workspace.

Comment: And why is your name eclipse-pmd? Are you the creator?

Comment: It's not the same plugin. The one you're using is officially called "PMD for Eclipse" and maintained by the same people that created PMD itself. The plugin I wrote is eclipse-pmd.

Comment: The workspace relative configuration in eclipse-pmd also works if the project files are linked into the workspace but are stored somewhere else in the file system. I.e. as long as you can see the rule set file in the Project Explorer in Eclipse you'll be fine.

Comment: Alright, i will check this out and report back, thank you!

Is there a specific reason you decided to write this plugin when the "official" plugin for PMD was already there? (Honestly curious here!)

Comment: I wrote the plugin because the other plugin was (maybe still is?) very hard to use with a team of developers. The biggest problem I had was to keep the set of rules consistent across the team as the other plugin keeps a separate copy of the rules for each project and needs a manual update from each developer for each project when the rule set was changed.
Also, I wanted to know how hard it is to write a plugin for Eclipse ;-).

Comment: Tested it and really liked it, seems to work like a charm. Good job on that! :)

Quick question: Is the update site (http://www.acanda.ch/eclipse-pmd/release/latest/) currently down?

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad you like it! The update site should be up and working. Do you have any problems accessing it?

Comment: I do, somehow. I cannot access it via the browser nor with eclipse. The connection times out in Eclipse and the browser gives me a "Forbidden"-Page. But if it is only me then it is probably our companys proxy going wild, for some reason :/

Comment: Ah, nevermind. For some reason my Eclipse deleted the proxy host configured and didnt say a word about it. 
And i guess the site is simply not accesible via the browser, i just thought i had it open in the browser once.

Comment: Any plans to do the global enable feature in the short term ?

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling a long time to get this working with *PMD for Eclipse*. While *Eclipse-PMD* has this feature built-in, I had some other issues with it (e.g. I think it is not meant to create reports).

The trick was adding the rules to the project as a *link*.

Create the rule file, e.g. pmd.xml, in the parent folder of the project. Add the file to the projects to be checked, but add it as a reference. Therefore, drag the file from the explorer to the bundle and select:

[image: File Operation Dialog]

In the project properties, in the *PMD* section, check *Enable PMD* and *Apply and Close* the settings.

Now close Eclipse. Edit the file with the name `.pmd` in the project folder by replacing the content with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pmd>
<useProjectRuleSet>true</useProjectRuleSet>
<ruleSetFile>pmd.xml</ruleSetFile>
<includeDerivedFiles>false</includeDerivedFiles>
<violationsAsErrors>true</violationsAsErrors>
<fullBuildEnabled>true</fullBuildEnabled>
</pmd>
```

Restart Eclipse and right click the project. Select PMD/Check Code. Now, only the violations defined in pmd.xml should be reported.

Configuring PMD only using the GUI does not seem to work for me.

Comment: Added information that enabling PMD in the project settings is also required